# Ensuring old and new key values have the same hash tag when using RENAME with Redis

Tags: redis

The Redis documentation mentions this caveat regarding the [RENAME](https://redis.io/commands/rename) command:

> In Cluster mode, both key and newkey must be in the same hash slot,
> meaning that in practice only keys that have the same hash tag can be
> reliably renamed in cluster.

I know that I can make sure my old and new key values have the same hash tag using the [CLUSTER KEYSLOT](https://redis.io/commands/cluster-keyslot) command, but what can I do if they don't? Keep picking random values until I find one that works?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the key-slot mapping, you should add a hash-tag in your keys. If your old key and new key both have the same hash tag, e.g. old: old-key-{hash-tag}, new: new-key-{hash-tag}, they are ensured to be located in the same hash slot, and you can rename it successfully.

If you cannot change your old key to add a hash-tag to it, you can use the old key as the hash-tag of the new key, e.g. old: old-key, new: {old-key}-new-key. This also ensures that both old key and new key located on the same slot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way you could give me some insight into why that is? Does the end of the key influence the hash value more than the beginning?